Where is the mistake in this proof about Bernoulli numbers?
In order to prove the well known identity $$B_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}S(n, k)\frac{k!(-1)^{k}}{k+1}$$ where $B_{n}$ is a Bernoulli number and $S(n, k)$ is a Stirling number of the second kind, I thought about integrating the well known formula $$D^{n}(f)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}S(n, k)u^{k}{f}^{(k)}\tag{1}$$ where $f$ is a function of the variable $u$ and $$D^{n}(f)=\underbrace{u(u(...u(u}_{n}f\overbrace{')'...)')'}^{n}$$
So integrating the RHS of $(1)$ between $1$ and $x$ (integration by parts) gives: $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}S(n, k)\int_{1}^{x}u^{k}{f}^{(k)}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}S(n, k){f}^{(k)}\frac{x^{k+1}}{k+1}-\sum_{k=1}^{n}S(n, k)\int_{1}^{x}{f}^{(k+1)}\frac{u^{k+1}}{k+1}$$
the integral of the LHS of $(1)$ gives: $$\int_{1}^{x}D^{n}(f)=\int_{1}^{x} u(\underbrace{u(...u(u}_{n-1}f\overbrace{')'...)'}^{n-1})'=\int_{1}^{x}uG'(u)=\left[uG(u)\right]_{1}^{x}-\int_{1}^{x}G(u)$$
where $G(u)=D^{n-1}(f)$
Rewriting the last equality in terms of $D$ we obtain
$$\int_{1}^{x}D^{n}(f(u))=\left[uD^{n-1}(f(u))\right]_{1}^{x}-\int_{1}^{x}D^{n-1}(f(u))$$
Replacing we get
$$\int_{1}^{x}D^{n}(f(u))=\left[\sum_{k=1}^{n}u(-1)^{k-1}D^{n-k}(f(u))\right]_{1}^{x}+(-1)^{n}\int_{1}^{x}f(u)$$
$\textbf{Conclusion}$
we have shown that
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}S(n, k){f}^{(k)}\frac{x^{k+1}}{k+1}-\sum_{k=1}^{n}S(n, k)\int_{1}^{x}{f}^{(k+1)}\frac{u^{k+1}}{k+1}=\left[\sum_{k=1}^{n}u(-1)^{k-1}D^{n-k}(f(u)) \right]_{1}^{x}+(-1)^{n}\int_{1}^{x}f(u)$$
Now set $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$, and use the formula $\forall k  \ \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{(k)}= \frac{(-1)^{k}k!}{x^{k+1}}$ you end up with:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}S(n, k)\frac{k!(-1)^{k}}{k+1}+\ln x\sum_{k=1}^{n}S(n, k)k!(-1)^{k}=\left[\sum_{k=1}^{n}u(-1)^{k-1}D^{n-k}\left(\frac{1}{u}\right) \right]_{1}^{x}+(-1)^{n}\ln x$$
Substitute $f$ by $\frac{1}{x}$ in $(1)$ we find that:$\sum_{k=1}^{n}S(n, k)k!(-1)^{k}=(-1)^{n}$ also, we can prove that $D^{n-k}\left(\frac{1}{u}\right)=\frac{(-1)^{n-k}}{u}$ so:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}S(n, k)\frac{k!(-1)^{k}}{k+1}=\left[n(-1)^{n-1}\right]_{1}^{x}\neq B_{n}$$
Absurd !

For a solution-verification question to be on topic you must specify precisely which step in the proof you question, and why so. This site is not meant to be used as a proof checking machine.

If $f$ a function of $u?$ Just define $Df$ rather than $D^nf,$ which requires ugly "..." definition. We can infer what $D^n$ means.

Now posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/480077/a-bernoulli-numbers-proof-that-fails

The MO copy has been deleted.
